# Allow saucelabs to use sauceconnect via proxy

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, saucelabs

I'm trying to setup **Sausage** with **Sauce connect**, using PHP API (via `phpunit`).

If I launch my tests from a server A, there is no problem when launching sauceconnect directly on server A: Sausage launched my tests via sauceconnect.

My concern is when trying to launch my tests from A, but having sauceconnect launched elsewhere, on a server B. What I want to do is to tell sausage to use B server to connect to sauce labs via sauceconnect, while launching my tests on A.

Tryed to add something like

```
'host' => 'my.server.with.sauceconnect.running',
'port' => xxxx
```

in the public `static $browsers array`, but it doesn't do the trick.

Have you got some good advices?

Thanks in advance!